# call.enqueue dont get called in Retrofit Android with Mvvm architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit

I am implementing get request with Retrofit in Mvvm architecture, but call.enqueue is not getting executed. When i try  it without mvvm architecture in simple activity it works fine.

Github:

https://github.com/nikolabozicbg/Retrofit

I tried to log onresponse and onfailure but nothing gets logged

Here is my Fragment code:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    listItemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(ListGamesViewModel.class);

    listItemViewModel.getListItems().observe(this, new Observer<List<ListGames>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<ListGames> listItems) {

        }
    });
}
```

View model code:

```
public class ListGamesViewModel extends ViewModel {
private RetrofitRpository repository;

public ListGamesViewModel(RetrofitRpository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

public LiveData<List<ListGames>> getListItems() {
    System.out.println("iz live model");
    return (LiveData<List<ListGames>>) repository.getListOfData();
}
```

}

Repository code:

```
public class RetrofitRpository {
List<ListGames> listItemList;

public RetrofitRpository() {
}

public List<ListGames> getListOfData() {

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://mobilews.365scores.com/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());


    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    LisgGamesCLient client = retrofit.create(LisgGamesCLient.class);
    Call<Example> call = client.reposForUser();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            System.out.println("onresponse");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("onfail");
        }
    });
    return listItemList;
}
```

}

CLient code:

```
public interface LisgGamesCLient {

@GET("Data/Games/?lang=1&uc=6&tz=15&countries=1")
Call<Example> reposForUser();
```

}

Example class code:

Comment: have you implemented the fragment class as `LifecycleOwner` ??

Comment: and where exactly did you pass the repository object ??

Comment: and also you returned a null list from the repository...this code is gonna burst... xD

Comment: i did not how to do that, btw when i put Retrofit logic to activity oncreate call.enqueue still dont get executed

Comment: Yes i return null list becouse call.enqueue  did not executed...

Comment: is onFailed gettimg called in activity ??

Comment: nope this is so wierd. But in antoher project whre i have only activity , Retrofit logig works fine ,  onresponse is executed with proper response

Comment: gimme the project link or i will send you the soln after m not in front of pc ryt now..

Comment: ok i will put it on github..

Comment: here is link :https://github.com/nikolabozicbg/Retrofit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165251/discussion-between-nikolas-bozic-and-santanu-sur).